# Pythonでexeファイルからバージョン情報の取得時に不要な文字列が含まれてしまう

Tags: python, python3, windows

ctypesでWindowsAPIを利用して、exeファイルからバージョン情報の製品名を取得しようとしています。
しかし、取得結果に不要な文字列がついてしまうことがあります。
何かよい対処法はないでしょうか。

### ソースコード

```
import array, ctypes, os

def getFileVersionInfo(name):
    if not os.path.exists(name):
        raise RuntimeError("The file %s does not exist" % name)
    size = ctypes.windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoSizeW(name, None)
    if not size:
        raise RuntimeError("No version information")
    res = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
    ctypes.windll.version.GetFileVersionInfoW(name, None, size, res)
    r = ctypes.c_uint()
    l = ctypes.c_uint()
    ctypes.windll.version.VerQueryValueW(res, u'\\VarFileInfo\\Translation',
        ctypes.byref(r), ctypes.byref(l))
    if not l.value:
        raise RuntimeError("No codepage")
    codepage = array.array('H', ctypes.string_at(r.value, 4))
    codepage = "%04x%04x" % tuple(codepage)
    if not ctypes.windll.version.VerQueryValueW(res, u'\\StringFileInfo\\%s\\%s' % (codepage, "ProductName"), ctypes.byref(r), ctypes.byref(l)):
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid or unavailable version info")
    else:
        return ctypes.wstring_at(r.value, l.value)

name="C:\\programs\\test.exe"
verInfo = getFileVersionInfo(name)
print(repr(verInfo))
```

### 出力結果

実際に設定されている製品名は、「TestApp」ですが、「TestApp」の後ろに不要な文字列がついてしまっています。
これを「TestApp」だけにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

```
'TestApp\x004\x0e\x01Pro'
```

環境は、Windows10 64ビット、Python 3.7です。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[`VerQueryValueW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluew)は状況によって文字数を返したりバイト数を返したりします。今回の場合、Unicode文字列のバイト数を返しているため、文字数としては値を半分にする必要があります。

実際、`TestApp\x004\x0e\x01Pro` は7文字14バイトのところを14文字取り出してしまっています。

Comment: なるほど。ということは、取り出すバイト数の指定がおかしいということでしょうか。もしよろしければ、何かヒントをいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: @user29034 何がわからないのか分からないので、説明のしようがないです。

Comment: 自分でもよくわかっていないのですが、わからないことは下記の2つだと思います。まず、文字数かバイト数のどちらを返しているかはどうやって判別すればいいでしょうか。また、今回の場合、バイト数が返ってきているとのことですが、Pythonでバイト数で取得する方法はあるのでしょうか。とりあえず、今は、\x00でsplitして、先頭の要素を取得していますが。